# Windows Server 2022: Install docker container runtime for Linux images using WSL without Hyper-V

Tags: linux, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-server

We want to install a docker container runtime on a (virtual) Windows Server 2022. This docker container should be able to run images on Linux (e.g. ubuntu). The server cannot run Hyper-V as it doesn't have the "required virtualization capabilities". However, WSL 2 is installed and runs Ubuntu. Docker Desktop at least suggests that the possibility exists, at least in non-server Windows installations:
[image: docker settings page that says: Use the WSL 2 based engine]

However,

- Docker for Desktop, which supports WSL, is not supported on Windows Server.
- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995973/linux-docker-container-on-windows-server-2016\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995973/linux-docker-container-on-windows-server-2016%5C)
  doesn't work because it requires Hyper-V, seems quite hacky
- https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-run-docker-containers-on-windows-server-2019/ 
  also requires Hyper-V

[Microsoft has announced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/set-up-environment?tabs=Windows-Server#install-docker) that Docker EE is on its way out and recommends "either [containerd](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/#containerd), [Moby](https://mobyproject.org/), or the [Mirantis Container Runtime](https://info.mirantis.com/docker-engine-support)".

Is there a way to use WSL 2 to run a Linux image in a Windows Server container runtime? And is there a recommended container runtime to do this with?

Comment: Wondering if you got the linux containers working in windows server 2022 using WSL 2?

Comment: @Edgaras No, ended up not using Docker at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a now a possibility to run Linux Containers on Windows Server 2022 using WSL 2 , for development and testing purposes, have a look at this [article from microsoft](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/using-wsl-2-on-windows-server-2022-to-run-linux-containers/ba-p/3624745?lightbox-message-images-3639744=408918i5F53A7F6896EA290)

Although it is quite a bit of work to get it running, specially the network part of it..